# Fastest Speed allowed for CW FM repeater ID in USA

Tags: united-states, legal, cw, repeater

What is the fastest legal WPM I can use for my repeater's Morse code identification?

I am in the USA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

20 wpm.

> §97-119:
>
> (b) The call sign must be transmitted with an emission authorized for
>   the transmitting channel in one of the following ways:
>
> (1) By a CW emission. When keyed by an automatic device used only for
>   identification, the speed must not exceed 20 words per minute;